# Echo Field Value In Text Field

Tags: php

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

Through some guidance I received earlier from this site I have been able to put together the script, below that lists date information with an associated radio button allowing each record to be selected.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");
?>
<html><head> 
<title>Location</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<form name="addimages">
  <p>
    <label>
    <div align="center" class="style3"> Location Name <br>
      <br>
      <input name="locationname" type="text" value="<?php echo $locationname;?>" id="locationname" size="80">
    </div>
    </label>
  </p> 
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid, detectinglocations.locationname,  finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
// table is empty
  echo 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.';
 else
{

  while (list($userid, $dateoftrip, $locationname) =
    mysql_fetch_row($result))

  {  
      echo"<table>\n"; 
      echo"<tr>\n"
    .
     "<td><input type='radio' name='radio' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' /></td>\n"
    ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n"
    ."</tr>\n";
  }
  echo"<tr><td colspan=\"3\">";
  echo"<br>";
  echo"</td></tr>";
  echo'</table>';
}
?>
</p>
</form>
```

What I'm now trying to do is add the 'locationname' value to the appropriate text field.

I've added `value="<?php echo $locationname;?>"` to the textfield but it remains blank.

I think that the problem lies here:

`while (list($userid, $dateoftrip, $locationname) = mysql_fetch_row($result))` which I use to get the information for the list of dates, whilst normally I would use this:
`while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $locationname = $row['locationname'];` to fetch the value for a text field.

Could someone perhaps tell me please is there a way that I can combine the two statements to bring together the two pieces of information I need i.e. the table containing the list of dates whilst 'echoing' the 'locationname' value into the text field.

Many thanks

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password")or
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");

$locationname=''; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userdetails.userid, finds.dateoftrip, finds.userid, finds.locationid, detectinglocations.locationid, detectinglocations.locationname,  finds.findname, finds.finddescription FROM userdetails, finds, detectinglocations WHERE finds.userid=userdetails.userid AND finds.locationid=detectinglocations.locationid AND finds.userid = 1 ORDER BY dateoftrip DESC");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
// table is empty
  $return = 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.'; 
  }else{     
  $return="<table>\n";     
  while (list($userid, $dateoftrip, $locationname) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){ 

$return .="<tr>\n". 
"<td><input type='radio' name='radio' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' /></td>\n" 
."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n" 
."</tr>\n"; 
} 
$return .="<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><br>"; 
} 
?>
<form name="addfinds">

      <input name="locationname" type="text" value="<?php echo $locationname;?>" id="locationname" size="80">   
  <p>&nbsp;</p> 
  <p> 
    <?php echo $return;?> 
</p> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to echo the variable before it is even assigned, move your while loop to include it inside.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your attempting to use it before setting it, if your had error_reporting on you would see the error. What you need toto is instead of using echos within your while loop, you should build the output and move the code above the input text. Something like this:

```
<?php
...
$locationname='';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
    $return = 'There are currently no finds recorded for this location.';
}else{
    $return="<table>\n";
    while (list($userid, $dateoftrip, $locationname) = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

        $return .="<tr>\n".
        "<td><input type='radio' name='radio' dateoftrip value='{$userid}' /></td>\n"
        ."<td><small>{$dateoftrip}</small><td>\n"
        ."</tr>\n";
    }
    $return .="<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><br>";
    ...
    ...
}

?>
<html><head> 
<title>Location</title>
...
...
      <input name="locationname" type="text" value="<?php echo $locationname;?>" id="locationname" size="80">
... 
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>
    <?php echo $return;?>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this. I've chnaged my code to include your suggestions and updated my original post. But unfortunately, although the query runs, the 'locationname' value is not populating the text field. Could you possibly let me know where I've gone wrong please?

Comment: i can onnly suggest you not use the `list($userid, $dateoftrip, $locationname)` approch and just use `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` then store `$locationname=$row['locationname']` when going through the loop

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should change ***while*** loop like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  list($userid, $dateoftrip, $locationname) = $row;

  // table
}
```